# How do I use SetActive to turn on my Player Object from my GameManager?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing an Asteroid clone and I am running up against an issue with re-spawning my player object after it is deactivated on collision with an asteroid. I run the SetActive(false) function to turn off the object from within the player object and when I try to use SetActive(true) from the GameManager to reactivate the Player object it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the section of code in the Player script where I turn off the  Player object:

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Asteroid")
        {
            _rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            _rigidbody.angularVelocity = 0.0f;


            this.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            GameManager.Instance.PlayerDeath();
        }
```

and here is the section of the GameManager where I try to reactivate the Player object:

```
 public void PlayerDeath()
    {
        this.lives--;

        if (this.lives <= 0)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
        else
        {
            //Invoke(nameof(Respawn), this.respawnTimer);
            StartCoroutine(Respawn(respawnTimer));

        }



    }

    public IEnumerator Respawn(float f)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(f);


        this.player.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        this.player.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the game object through to the PlayerDeath method, then you won't need to set the active state unless they die.

Comment: Are you sure the `player` referenced to the `GameManager` and the `player` to which the player script is attached are same?

Comment: Is the `position` of the player being updated?

Comment: @GeekyQuentin I am sure that the player referenced is the Player object. The position of the player is not updated when it's destroyed, it's supposed to reset to the center of the screen before re-spawning.

Comment: I think I've found the solution. In my GameManager I was referencing the prefab for my Player object rather than the Player object in the hierarchy/on screen. As soon as I swapped them everything started working as it should. Thanks very much for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Is your GameOver method will call IEnumerator Respawn? 
if not then I think that's your problem, cause what I know so far is that 
an `if` statement will executed and if it's True if not True then it will be an `Else` statement, in your case your IEnumerator was inside `Else` statement try to move it above.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).